# How to read frequency of all CPU cores at once?

Tags: c, linux, bash, cpu

I would like to get current frequency of all CPU cores in a given moment.

When I do:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

I get following values:

```
803808
900124
900007
900040
900031
900025
900003
900005
```

Are they different, because each core is working with slightly different frequency? Or because there is some time between reading different files, corresponding to different cores?

What is the proper way to read all CPU cores frequency at once in Linux? (`C` or `BASH`)

Comment: They are slightly different because power saving. You OS scales the CPU speed down to save energy.

Comment: Why is it important that you read them the exact same microsecond?

Comment: I agree with @KamilCuk above. In C, you can minimize any time difference by opening the pseudofiles first, then read from them using [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to a sufficiently large buffer each, say 32 bytes per read, and parse them only after reading.  That way any time difference is neglible, literally on the order of syscall cost in the typical case (because these are sysfs attributes); and you can safely consider the frequencies as a "concurrent snapshot".

Answer (score -2):

You can read this infomation by this bash command:

```
 cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: on one of my computers CPU frequency info isn't listed in `/proc/cpuinfo` :(

Comment: `lscpu` shows only one value (doesn't show all cores values). BTW do you know what value is this? Mean? First core?

Comment: @user2449761 lscpu show what frequency CPU can be.
scaling_cur_freq  this is a current frequency